# Redirecting to a login page

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating a demo admin panel where an administrator will have to login in order to have access to the records of an example food business' order history, however I can easily just type in the url of this 'private' page which is only supposed to be accessed by the logged in administrator. How would I make it so that if a user where to type in this url that they will be redirected to the login page for access if they are not logged in?

I believe using php sessions could be on the right track? Any advice would be great

Comment: Yep sessions are important for this. You can definitely fine examples of how to build a simple login system online already, there are loads of tutorials/blogs/questions about it already. You shouldn't need to be stuck on a fairly basic part of it like this. Or...just skip this and use a framework which already provides a ready made authentication module so you don't have to go through the effort and pain, and you don't make any mistakes leading to security holes in your application

Answer (score 0):

In the private page check presence of the session if the session is not set then the user has not logged in redirect to the logging in page from there. You can redirect using header('location':'login.php');